# Problems with scanf

Tags: c

I'm having problems with this snippet of code:

```
   while(scanf("%d",&numOfPlayers)!=1){
        printf("Please enter the right number of players");    
    }
```

My purpose is to read a number from the user, and keep asking as long as the input isn't an int. When I run this snippet and input 'r' for example, I get stuck in an infinite loop. What might be the problem, and how can I improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `scanf()` can't read the input, it actually doesn't read it, so it reads the same input over and over again in your example. You can discard the invalid input like this:

```
while(scanf("%d",&numOfPlayers)!=1){
  scanf("%s");
  printf("Please enter the right number of players\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you please cite a source backing up your claim that `scanf("%s")` is safe?

Comment: “If the number of conversion specifications in format exceeds the number of pointer arguments, the results are undefined.” So the result depends on the compiler and may be unpredictable.

Comment: Exactly, so you shouldn't be advocating doing that.  Also, *undefined* behavior is distinct from *unspecified* and *implementation-defined* behavior.  It means that *anything* at all can happen; you must not depend on it even for a specific compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Try scanning for a string into a buffer and then searching that string for your number with sscanf().

Comment: how can I do it without sscanf?

Comment: you could check the return of atoi() instead of using sscanf()

Comment: `atoi` will give no indication of failure. Use `strtol`/`strtoul` instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Won't atoi() return 0 on failure? I know that it's a poor return value considering that it returns the converted number on success and if the user entered 0 you're out of luck, but that is why I initially suggested the use of sscanf() instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the comp.lang.c FAQ: [Why does everyone say not to use `scanf`? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)